# http_proxy is set but where?

Tags: 14.04, proxy

For some reason I have the proxy set:

```
$ echo $http_proxy
http://123.456.11.11:80/
```

But I can't find where it is, `~/.bashrc, ~/.profile` and `/etc/bashrc` don't contain it. And in System->Setting it's not set either. So how do I find out where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set in /etc/environment.This sets the variable for every user,system wide

Comment: I removed it but after reboot http_proxy is set again. /etc/env-t doesn't hold it.

Comment: Go to System Settings->Network.Change Network Proxy's method(in drop down) to None,and apply changes system wide.Restart,and it should work.If it doesn't try env | grep http_proxy in terminal and see where it is set

Comment: of course, it's None.

Comment: check in /etc/wgetrc and /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ .These are the possible locations where system wide settings  can be found,other than /etc/environment